# Mounting multiple files with same extension via docker run

Tags: docker

I am aware that a single file, say `hello_world.py`, in my local file system can be **mounted** (not copied) on a docker container by

```
docker run -v local_directory/hello_world.py:docker_directory/hello_world.py other_params
```

My question is if it is possible to use a similar syntax to **mount** multiple files with the **same extension** in a directory to a docker container? I was experimenting with using `*.py` to no avail.

```
docker run -v local_directory/*.py:docker_directory/*.py other_params
```

Is my only option to explicitly write individual `-v` statements for each `.py` file in the `docker run` command?

Comment: Any reason not to mount the entire directory?

Comment: I can't do that since the directory in the docker container has several necessary executables that aren't present in my local file system.

Answer (score 2):

While `*`-formatted mappings are not possible, there are certainly ways around it so you don't have to individually map each file.  One possibility is to mount the `local_directory` into the container, then create symlinks using a `for()` loop:

```
docker run -v local_directory:custom_directory other_params
for i in `ls local_directory/*py`
do
  docker exec -it ln -s custom_directory/${i} docker_directory <container_name>
done
```

Comment: This looks great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible to use relative paths at all to mount files in Docker, nor use regular expressions as of `Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc`

Answer (score 1):

A clean sollution for your case would be to mount the entire folder and use a command to point the executables to the correct folder such as:

```
 docker run -v my_folder:/docker/my_folder python:3 python /docker/my_folder/my-script.py
```

[more info](https://hub.docker.com/_/python)